# Fixing contamination factor for isolation forest

Tags: anomaly-detection

I have different data sets (for say IDs columns being same) for which I want to identify the anomalies but each data set have different percentages of anomalies present. Since I am using the isolation forest I would need to set different contamination factor to increase accuracy. Does any one have any suggestions how can this contamination factor be fixed.

Comment: If you have different datasets then you might need different contamination factors per dataset. You can plot a histogram for each dataset and then decide which contamination factor you want to use.

Comment: Ideally tune using hyperparameter optimization on a validation set